# Multiply value by -1 if column x contains a string

Tags: excel

Basically what i want to do is to express my excel column sum in -ve if the value in **Action** is `Sell`. If its `Buy` then don't do anything. Currently, I am doing sum like `=B2+C2` but it will always be in +ve no matter if it is representing a purchase or sell order.

Here is some sample data

[image]

Notice how **Net** column shows +ve value even though one value is `Sell` and the other one is `Buy`. I want `Sell` to be displayed as +ve value and `Sell` to be shown as -ve value.

Comment: Your question is still unclear. Please include some sample data and the formulas you're using, with the expected output and explain where you're stuck.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: The formula you're looking for in your `Net` column is something close to `=IF(B2="Buy",F2+G2,IF(B2="Sell",F2-G2,NA()))`. This assumes that `Ticker` is in column A. Adjust it as you need to.

Comment: But I see what you were asking originally, sorry. If you store your commission value in a separate cell (in my example I stored `11.95` in cell `M2`), then your **Net** formula is `=F2+G2` and the formula in **Commision** will be `=IF(B2="Buy",$M$2,IF(B2="Sell",-$M$2,NA()))`

Comment: Used this formula `=IF(B2="Buy", G2+F2, IF(B2="Sell", -G2+F2, NA()))` but it didn't work out.

Comment: Change the second math part to `G2-F2` and try that

Comment: Commission still get added to the number. The only thing is that the final number could be -ve or +ve.

Comment: The answer I get in **Net** for the Buy is 233.95. The answer I get for Sell is 192.05. Isn't that correct?

Comment: No, it's not. The answer for `Sell` should be -215.95 i.e., same as before just with -ve sign. Anyway, I figure it out. here is the final formula that i used `=IF(B2="Buy", G2+F2, -1*(G2+F2))`

Comment: @Bad_Neighbor: These are two unrelated transactions which i put in just as a sample.

Comment: my apologies, comment removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use `=IF(B2="Buy", G2+F2, -1*(G2+F2))` to solve my problem.